# Ambiguous without more context error in Swift

Tags: swift

I have just updated Swift and I am getting an error on these lines.

Error 1:

> Expression type '[(NSLayoutAttribute, Double)]' is ambiguous without more context

```
// create constraints
for info: (attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, scale: CGFloat)  in [(NSLayoutAttribute.width, 0.8), (NSLayoutAttribute.height, 0.9)] {
```

and Error 2:

> Expression type '[(NSLayoutAttribute, Int)]' is ambiguous without more context

```
for info: (attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, offset: CGFloat)  in [(NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, 0), (NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, 30)] {
```

Comment: You seem to declare the function as accepting `(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, offset: CGFloat)`, but you pass `(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, offset: int)`, try [(NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, CGFloat(0)), (NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, CGFloat(30))]

Comment: Thank you user9335240 this solved my issue.

Comment: You have labels on the type declaration but not the tuple literals, try adding them.

Comment: If @user9335240's comment has solved your issue, you can delete your question or have him/her post the comment as an answer so others with the same problem can quickly find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to declare the function as accepting

```
(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, offset: CGFloat)
```

But you pass

```
(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, offset: int)
```

Try

```
[(NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, CGFloat(0)), (NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, CGFloat(30))]
```

Int is not directly convertible to float